# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

i have this in `main.py`:

```
TODOS = {
    'todo1': {'task': 'build an API'},
    'todo2': {'task': '?????'},
    'todo3': {'task': 'profit!'},
}


class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify(TODOS)

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/api')
```

and in client side i use from angularjs:

```
var url = "/api?q=" + 'fdsf' + "&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
  console.log("get");
  this.busy = false;
}.bind(this));
```

but when i load page i have this error in console:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement


"todo1": {
```

how i can fix this error? why jsonify function not work?

EDIT

**in chromium:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

**in firefox:**

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement


"todo1": {
```

Comment: I think the problem might be the extra comma at the end of this line 'todo3': {'task': 'profit!'},

Comment: @doodeec No, that extra `,` won't raise an error in Python.

Comment: @doodeec nope - trailing delimiters are fine in Python...

Comment: @doodeec: That's Python code, where such commas are allowed.

Comment: again I'm a little smarter now :)

Comment: fyi, jsonp isn't so safe, data can be stolen (hijacked). better to use CORS (cross origin resource sharing)

Comment: @Endless how i can use from CROS?

Comment: @28 http://enable-cors.org/

put some extra headers and use regular GET request and use plan JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `jsonp`, but your response returns plain JSON.

[JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (or *JSON with padding*) should include a *callback* function, not a plain JSON response.

You should use [`$http.get()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#methods_get) here, *not* `$http.jsonp()`.